Google OAuth API throws TypeError in a React+TS project
Everytime a user visit the OAuth url, my program throws exception as follows:
"TypeError: Failed to execute 'query' on 'Permissions': illegal invocation"
while the page stucks up with infinite loading.
I did setup my project in Google Cloud Console.

Added https://localhost and https://localhost:5173 to 'Authorized JavaScript origins'

Added https://localhost:5173 to 'Authorized redirect URIs'


I enabled Google+ API and Contacts API in Google Cloud Console.
And tried adding Google login feature to my app as follows:
//App.tsx
function App() {
    const clientId: string = '12345678901-a1b2c3a1b2c3a1b2c3a1b2c3a1b2c3a1.apps.googleusercontent.com';//edited

    return (
        
        <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={clientId}>
            <GoogleLogin/>
        </GoogleOAuthProvider>
    );
}

//App.tsx
function App() {
    const clientId: string = '12345678901-a1b2c3a1b2c3a1b2c3a1b2c3a1b2c3a1.apps.googleusercontent.com';//edited
    const handleGoogleLogin = () => {
        window.location.href = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5173&response_type=code&scope=email+profile`
    }
    return (
        <button onClick={handleGoogleLogin}/>
    );
}

export default App;

The exception occured in both implementation.
